# Incorrect Export of Report from Access to Excel. The records in the Excel file keep repeating the same record

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Was wondering if anyone has encountered this problem. I'm working on an Access 2013 database which produces a couple of reports. These reports need to be exported into Excel files. I do this in VBA by using

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "ReportName", acFormatXLS, "fileName.xls"
```

The files are created, however, their contents don't look as expected, especially when compared to the resulting XLSX files obtained by running the built-in Access' "External Data"->"Export to Excel spreadsheet" function.
For example, in one of the files, the rows of the table obtained by running report's row source query do not advance, resulting in multiple repetitions of the same row. In the other one the formatting is wrong.
Again, when exporting using the Access built-in "Export to Excel" function, the results are correct.
Question: is there an alternate method of exporting reports to Excel? Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks!

Note:  this is a copy of a question asked by user Coder014 some time ago.  There wasn't an answer given in his question and I just came across the exact same problem today. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you do "External Data -> Export" operation from ribbon, this is exporting query and works? It's not uncommon for complex reports to not export nicely so I am guessing this is a complex report with Sorting & Grouping and calculations. Your issue is likely with design and there is no code for us to analyze therefore question is not really suited to SO.

Comment: Thanks for your note.  My report does have Sorting and Grouping (no calculations).  About the Code, the entire Sub I'm using is the 1 line of code I included in my question (preceded by "Sub btnExportToExcel()" and followed by "End Sub").  Nothing fancy in the Code.  An issue may be that I put the command button on the Report itself (not on the Form that opens the Report).

Comment: Command buttons are not clickable for report in PrintPreview. ReportView is probably why the Excel output is odd.

Comment: Thanks - I think that's the problem. I'll just do an Export to Excel of the underlying Table instead of trying to export the Report.